# How to efficiently loading millions of domain objects

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am facing to problem since I have millions of domain objects in one table. When I try to get all objects by using Domain.findAllBy() after couple of minutes I get OutOfMemoryError.. I would like to know if there is an efficient way to load all of them without getting this error again ?

Should I page the result and only load the necessaries ?

Please tell me if I am doing it wrong as well..

Thank you for your help and happy new year ;)

Comment: Result pagination is a good idea :) Other option is to buy more memory ;)

Comment: Hi MariuszS, I have already 10GB allocated to the heap. The problem is that more I give and more the app take, I am just wondering if there is a way to make it a bit more efficient without playing with pagination and filters.

Comment: If you want to load everything in one hit, making more memory available is your only option. It really depends what you are trying to do though - there may be other ways of approaching the problem that avoid loading everything into memory in one shot. If you don't need all the columns, you could create a cut-down domain object and use that instead, for example, to cut down on the memory overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real solution is not to try to retrieve all domain objects in one go into memory. No matter how much memory you buy, you can't guarantee that the domain objects won't grow more quickly than your RAM.

Next, even if you could store all the objects in memory, it would take a non-trivial amount of time to retrieve them all. Any operations you want to undertake on the objects - modifying attributes, calling methods - would take even longer.

I can't imagine a scenario where a human user would want to see millions of business objects on a web page - even paging through them all doesn't make sense.

So, if you are retrieving the objects to modify them, do so in the database. If you are retrieving them to run a method on the business objects, use paging, or consider if you can implement that method as a database call. If you're retrieving them for display, you'll need to allow the user to filter their request, and provide pagination.

Comment: Thank you Neville for your explanation, I guess you are right.. There is no magic ! I have to rethink how I am loading these millions of objects...